# Sending big values to wallet

Tags: web3js, nodejs, bignumber

I want to send big value (10000000) for example to other wallet but i have error like this:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number 3.0244e+22 to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "3.0244e+22"
```

My code:

```
 const myAddress = web3.eth.defaultAccount;
      const gasPrice = new BN(await web3.eth.getGasPrice()).mul(new BN(toSend));
      const gasLimit = 6721900;
      const value = toSend* 1e18; 
      const from = web3.eth.defaultAccount;
      const to = wallet_id;
```

Comment: "new BN(await web3.eth.getGasPrice()).mul(new BN(toSend))" why are you using .mul here? what is "toSend" and what is the purpose of .mul?

Comment: and value should probably: const value = new BN("1000000000000000000").mul(new BN(toSend));

Answer (score 0):

if you use ether.js you  can do it easy like that :
ethers.utils.parseEther('1') || ethers.utils.parseEther('0.01') ||